# How can I check my bookmarks in Chrome for broken links?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

For years I have been creating bookmarks in Google Chrome and now there are so many (around 2000) that I would spend days checking one by one to make sure that the URLs are still valid, and that the sites and or pages haven't gone away.

How could I automate checking these bookmarks for broken links and, ideally, remove bookmarks with invalid URLs?

I'm running Chrome on Windows 7.

Answering Rich Homolka: by "broken" I mean "kaput", not working, damaged, something that has ceased to perform the function for which was created.

Comment: Website bookmarks? Which browser?

Comment: Hi Fernando. I rewrote your question to focus on the *problem*, not assuming there's a program to do it. You've indeed told us more about the problem but you still haven't even told us what browser and operating system you're using. You won't be able to get an answer without this information.

Comment: Also, what's broken mean? No website? 404? A huge subset of what you'd consider "broken" will be landing pages or redirects. A .com domain is too valuable to leave empty and a lot of links will be active but *not* pointing to the content you originally cared about.

Comment: @RichHomolka I'd presume he means anything with either a 404 response code, or host not found. For the most part, web sites that display custom "page not found" pages still send a 404 response in the header.